# VBA excel - Delete rows, each sheet with different conditions

Tags: excel, vba, rows

In a previous questions, I wanted to delete rows in sheet under different numeric conditions.

Now I wanna do the same thing but in multiple sheets, and each sheet would have its own delete conditions.

The problem I have is I don't know how to set or select the sheet in witch I want the code to be executed.

Here's the code I have ( Tim Williams helped a lot with this one)  :

```
Sub loopanddelete()

Dim i As Long, fVal, gVal
Dim ws As Worksheet, rngDel As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False

Set ws = Sheets("209990")

For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then
    fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
    gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
       If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
          If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal >= 1 And gVal <= 12)) And _
           Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal >= 1 And fVal <= 12)) Then
            BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    End If
 End If

 If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
   fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
   gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

   If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
        If Not (fVal = 55 And ((gVal >= 1 And gVal <= 12) Or gVal = 55)) And _
           Not (gVal = 55 And ((fVal >= 1 And fVal <= 12) Or fVal = 55)) Then
            BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
   End If
 End If

Next i
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows

 Set ws = Sheets("209991")

    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

         If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then

       fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
       gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then

        If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal= 51 Or gVal=53)) And _
           Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =51 Or fVal =53)) Then
            BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
         End If
       End If
     End If

      If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
      fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
      gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

       If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
        If Not (fVal = 55 And ((gVal= 51 Or gVal=53)or gVal=55)) And _
           Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =51 Or fVal =53)or fVal=55) Then
            BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
           End If
       End If
     End If

     Next i
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows


  Set ws = Sheets("209995")

  For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
      If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then
    fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
    gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
    If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
        If Not (fVal = 55 And gVal= 45) And _
           Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =45)) Then
            BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
       End If
    End If

   If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
   fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
   gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
        If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal= 45 or gVal=55)) And _
           Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =45 or fVal=55)) Then
            BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
   End If
   End If
 Next i
   If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows



   Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
  If rngTot Is Nothing Then
     Set rngTot = rngAdd
   Else
       Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
   End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: `Set ws = Sheets("209990")` <--- this (and similar lines) sets the worksheet so a bit unclear what the issue is. But if the delete criteria is different across worksheets, consider creating a separate subroutine for each sheet.

Comment: I get error 1004 with setting each sheet each time. Iif I don't get any other better solution, that's what I'll do.. Thank youu

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: It looks like you're missing an `End Sub`. The first sub needs to end before you start the next sub.

Comment: the End Sub is just a typo, I have in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if the information being assessed is all on the one row:

```vb
Sub ProcessSheets()

    RemoveRowsByExpression Sheets("209990"), _
        "=NOT(OR(AND(F@=55,AND(G@>=1,G@<=12)),AND(G@=55,AND(F@>=1,F@<=12))))"
    
    RemoveRowsByExpression Sheets("209991"), _
        "=NOT(OR(AND(F@=44,AND(G@>=1,G@<=19)),AND(G@=44,AND(F@>=1,F@<=19))))"
    
End Sub

' expr = valid Excel formula (with @ as row placeholder) to determine
'     which rows are to be deleted
Sub RemoveRowsByExpression(ws As Worksheet, expr As String)

    Dim i As Long, fVal, gVal, s
    Dim c As Range, rngDel As Range 'this range holds the rows to be deleted
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'not sure if you really need this...
    
    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'loop backwards
        Set c = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        If c.Value <> ws.Name Then   'Col A check
            expr = Replace(expr, "@", i)
            If ws.Evaluate(expr) Then 'if expression return true then remove the row
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = c
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, c)
                End If
            End If
       End If
    Next i
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows
End Sub
```